# What is the purpose of rotating filters while building convolutions with scipy signal?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scipy, conv-neural-network

I recently came across a bit of python code (shown below) which does 2d convolution with scipy signal.

```
x = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]],
              dtype='float')

w_k = np.array([[1, 0, 1],
                [0, 1, 0],
                [1, 0, 1],],
                dtype='float')

w_k = np.rot90(w_k, 2)

f = signal.convolve2d(x, w_k, 'valid')
```

Right before the convolve2d operation, the filter was rotated. What is the purpose of that?

Comment: Because whoever did it didn't know about `signal.correlate()`?  Although in this case it's pretty useless since the kernel is super-symmetric.

Comment: Can you tell me why that rotation was needed with convolve2d? And what is the significance of symmetry here?